# Paypal IPN History Show Nothing

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I use code from here : https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples
I tried the IPN Simulator : https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/
and got this message : IPN was sent and the handshake was verified.
but when i checked my IPN history it shows nothing, no data 
What should i do?

Comment: Which sample are you using? Did you check for error logs?

Comment: i use this one : PaypalIPN.php, sorry i'm new to this how to check error logs?

Comment: Which server are you using to serve your php?

Comment: i'm using apache

Comment: If you are on Linux the logs are somewhere like /var/log/apache/error.log

Comment: Hello Alan, i got a payment last night but this payment wasn't coming from my store (it was from my other business but the email for receiving payment is the same as my online store email for receving payment) and the IPN history shows the data : https://imgur.com/a/SrHQG4F

Comment: This mean my IPN already working correctly?

Comment: I just found out the simple way to integrate the IPN by simply installing the plugin and it works now, Thanks Alan for your times